# How provides to use small area while compressing and decompressing in java?

Tags: java, zip, buffer, compression

I have a huge data and when it entered in TextZip class it covers area in RAM about 2 GB. I couldn't solve how can I make smaller that area. What should I change in that class? Any alternative or technic for provide speed and small area while compressing and decompressing in java?
Here is my class which name is TextZip.java ==>

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/bd72fee48e1c3f8812ece187080e452e

Best Regards.

Comment: What **huge data** does mean exactly? Does it mean that your pass very long string as input parameter for `compress()` and `decompress()` methods respectively?

Comment: 3627829 byte is been compressed. When it decompresses it becomes 129531542 byte. It covers area 2 GB in RAM. Sometimes it throw "OutOfMemory" error. What is alternative to TextZip class for provides to cover small area on RAM?

Answer (score 0):

In `TextZip` class `ByteArrayOutputStream` accumulates uncompressed data and grows dynamically. But it always holds all data in RAM. This is why you get `OutOfMemory` error.

Consider something like this (I've omitted exception catching for brevity):

```
    ...
    OutputStream outputFile = new FileOutputStream("uncompressed"); // uncompressed data will be stored into file
    byte[] smallBuf = new byte[1024000];
    ByteArrayOutputStream largeBuf = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    while (!decompressor.finished()) {
        int count = decompressor.inflate(smallBuf);
        largeBuf.write(smallBuf, 0, count);
        if (largeBuf.size() > 1024000 * 10) { // we already accumulated large chunk of data
            largeBuf.writeTo(outputFile);     // so it's time to write it to disk
            largeBuf.flush();
            largeBuf = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); // prepare for next large chunk
        }
    }
    ...
```

In the snippet above not all uncompressed data reside in RAM (obviously, 2GB is too much). But writing each small chunk of data into file (or sending to network) is inefficient (because of I/O overhead). So we accumulate uncompressed data into large chunk (something about 10 Mega Bytes) and then write these 10MB to disk.

Generally speaking, it's a question of balance. Residing all uncompressed data in RAM is fast, but limited by amount of available memory. Keeping small chunks of uncompressed data in RAM is slow due to I/O. Tune up condition inside loop for you machine.

Comment: at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[1,1]
Message: Content is not allowed in prolog.
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl.next(XMLStreamReaderImpl.java:594)
 at com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.StaxReader.pullNextEvent(StaxReader.java:58)
 ... 31 more It throws this ERROR. What should do?

Answer (score 0):

```
        public static synchronized String decompress(String compressedData) throws IOException {
        // Create the decompressor and give it the data to compress
//        Inflater decompressor = new Inflater();
        byte[] buffer = new Base64Encoder().decode(compressedData);
//    System.out.println("Created string from bytes by base 64 encoding");
        OutputStream outputFile = new FileOutputStream("unCompressed");
        byte[] smallBuf =new byte[1024];
        decompressor.setInput(buffer);
        // Create an expandable byte array to hold the decompressed data
        ByteArrayOutputStream largeBuf = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        // Decompress the data
        byte[] buf = new byte[10240];
        while (!decompressor.finished()) {

            try {
                int count = decompressor.inflate(buf);
                largeBuf.write(smallBuf, 0, count);
                if (largeBuf.size()>10240*10) {
                    largeBuf.writeTo(outputFile);
                    largeBuf.flush();
                    largeBuf=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                }
            } catch (DataFormatException e) {
//                  System.out.println("Exception " + e);
            }

        }
        try {
            largeBuf.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }

        // Get the decompressed data
        byte[] decompressedData = largeBuf.toByteArray();

        decompressor.reset();
//        decompressor.end();

        return new String(decompressedData);
    }
```

I redesign my decompress method. Is it true?